# Doctrine entity don't trigger PostUpdate event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

```
<?php

namespace Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="warehouse_item")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $codepath;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $filepath;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="itemreserved")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $reservedby;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="51200k",
     * maxSizeMessage = "Plik ma więcej niż 50 megabajtów",
     * mimeTypes = {
     *          "image/png",
     *          "image/jpeg",
     *          "image/jpg",
     *          "image/gif",
     *          "application/pdf",
     *          "application/x-pdf",
     *          "application/msword",
     *          "application/zip",
     *          "application/x-rar-compressed",
     *          "application/excel"
     *      },
     * mimeTypesMessage = "Zły format!"
     * )
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var $removefile if set, remove file
     */
    private $removefile;


    private $temp;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->resservedby = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set codepath
     *
     * @param string $codepath
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setCodepath($codepath)
    {
        $this->codepath = $codepath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get codepath
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCodepath()
    {
        return $this->codepath;
    }

    /**
     * Set filepath
     *
     * @param string $filepath
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setFilepath($filepath)
    {
        $this->filepath = $filepath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filepath
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFilepath()
    {
        return $this->filepath;
    }

    /**
     * Add category
     *
     * @param \Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addCategory(\Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove category
     *
     * @param \Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Category $category
     */
    public function removeCategory(\Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Add resservedby
     *
     * @param \Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $resservedby
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addResservedby(\Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $resservedby)
    {
        $this->resservedby[] = $resservedby;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove resservedby
     *
     * @param \Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $resservedby
     */
    public function removeResservedby(\Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $resservedby)
    {
        $this->resservedby->removeElement($resservedby);
    }

    /**
     * Get resservedby
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getResservedby()
    {
        return $this->resservedby;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setCategory(\Raltech\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set resservedby
     *
     * @param \Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $resservedby
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setResservedby(\Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $resservedby = null)
    {
        $this->resservedby = $resservedby;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add reservedby
     *
     * @param \Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $reservedby
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addReservedby(\Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $reservedby)
    {
        $this->reservedby[] = $reservedby;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove reservedby
     *
     * @param \Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $reservedby
     */
    public function removeReservedby(\Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $reservedby)
    {
        $this->reservedby->removeElement($reservedby);
    }

    /**
     * Get reservedby
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getReservedby()
    {
        return $this->reservedby;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->filepath
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->filepath;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->filepath
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().''.$this->filepath;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/itemsdata/';
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        if (isset($this->file)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->filepath;
            $this->filepath = null;
        } else {
            $this->filepath = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
            $this->filepath = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'-'.$this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // move takes the target directory and then the
        // target filename to move to
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->filepath
        );

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }



        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * Get removefile
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRemovefile()
    {
        return $this->removefile;
    }

    /**
     * set removefile (remove file)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function setRemovefile($removefile = null)
    {
        $this->removefile = $removefile;
        if($removefile) {
            $path = $this->getAbsolutePath();

            if (file_exists($path)) {
                unlink($path);
                $this->filepath = null;

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        if ($file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set reservedby
     *
     * @param \Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $reservedby
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setReservedby(\Raltech\UserBundle\Entity\User $reservedby = null)
    {
        $this->reservedby = $reservedby;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My entity,
Function upload should be trigger on PostCreate(this works fine) and PostUpdate but on update doesn't trigger.I'm doing something wrong? Update is smillar to coockbook ( get item, persist,flush).

Comment: Can you put your php code where you're updating your entity ?

Comment: Solved, issue was a exacly equal, change to ``if (null == $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }`` solved issue